# php exec returning sh: 1: 'not found'

Tags: php

So I've installed 'translate-toolkit' to use 'po2txt', everything works fine when I run it in terminal. But when I try run it in a php file,

```
<?php

exec('po2txt --version');
```

I get *sh: 1: po2txt: not found*

I'm really unsure about what I've missed, if I run for example

```
<?php

exec('git --version');
```

It returns normally. So I guess I'm unsure as to why it works when I use it in terminal but if I try execute it through a php file it isn't found..

Comment: Where did you install `po2txt`? Is your user `PATH` different from the system `PATH`? Try using the absolute path, `exec('/path/to/po2txt --version');`.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the installation path of `po2txt`? 
You can simply find it by running this command in terminal: `which po2txt` 
check the path of `po2txt` is exists in your `PATH` variable?